# Import csv file with less columns than the table to which I'm importing?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin, load-data-infile

I have exported a csv file with four columns in phpMyAdmin whith these options:

```
Columns separated with:  ,
Columns enclosed with:   "
Columns escaped with:    "
Lines terminated with:   AUTO
```

Now I want to import this file into a table with 17 columns!? 
So only four columns will be populated and the others will stay empty.

Comment: What is your actual question? What have you tried, what were the results?

Comment: I tried as @have suggested and it's giving me Error #1064

Comment: @JetonThaçi:- I modifeid the query, try now.  I suggest that you first try without the LINES TERMINATED BY... clause. Let MySQL auto-detect this for you.

If this does not work, try again, this time with only \n, or only \r.

Sorry - I can't provide with a definite answer, you'll have to test..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spcify the column name while import data from file, and use user variable to discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable while import data in table .

<kbd>[AS PER MYSQL DOCUMENTATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)</kbd>

> You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable
>   and not assigning the variable to a table column:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, @dummy,
>   column2, @dummy, column3);

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv'  
INTO TABLE sqlTable(column1, column2, column3, column4, @NotInsert2, @NotInsert2... till @NotInsert13);
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

So in Your case, Just specify four column name, and use any user variable instead of others column name so that total number of column in list will be equal to 17.

**EDIT** - Lets understand with Example:-

Consider we have to load file with following contents:
File-name: example.csv

```
col-2,col-3,col-4
a,2,3
b,4,5
c,6,7
```

Case :- When csv file have lesser number of columns than targeted table

table structure: tablename 
col-1 col-2 col-3 col-4

Consider, col-1 is auto-increment and not provided in csv.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ‘path/to/example.csv’ 
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ 
LINES
TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ 
IGNORE 1 LINES (col-2,col-3,col-4) set col-1=null;
```

Passing null value will make col-1 to take an auto-increment value.
Using SET you can assign values to those columns which were not available in csv and are not null.

For more information <kbd>[refer here](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/load-data-csv-to-mysql.pdf)</kbd>

Comment: The csv file is imported successfully, but instead of inserting 1560 rows, it's inserting 37865 rows and they're all empty. Any idea why  is this going on???

Comment: are you used FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' or not , so that it will not insert all row from csv where no data

Comment: No I didn't use that line. How should it be?

Comment: used after that query , so add after you specified column name

Comment: I read the documentation but I still don't get it, how should I put that last line, can you please help me? In the question you have the options I choose for making the csv file. Thank you.

Comment: I already tried your line and a bunch of other combinations, but they're all giving me errors.

Comment: It's still giving me an error. (#1064 ... near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY 'AUTO'' at line 3 )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'XYZ.csv'
     INTO TABLE tickets  
FIELDS  terminated by ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (column1, column2, column3, column4)(choose your data columns) ";
```

Comment: I think the solution of @HaveNoDisplayName was working except that last line: FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY 'AUTO', it's not set properly according to my csv options.

Comment: I tried as @havenodisplayname suggested and it's giving me Error #1064